# FindControl and innertext includes formatting characters, how to remove?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a span element that has `runat=server`

I am trying to read its value in the code behind like this

```
spanspanBoxCode = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("spanBoxCode");
```

However, when I look at `spanspanBoxCode.InnerText`, instead of the actual string value, it includes some formatting like this:

```
{InnerText = "\r\n                                        [da6f7e70-e16b-4a38-aaa0-96456ye14b1]\r\n                                    "}
```

How can I remove that formatting?  I know its not in the original source data as I am stepping through that just before its used to populate that element.

I need just the actual value of `da6f7e70-e16b-4a38-aaa0-96456ye14b1`

Where is that extra padding and control characters coming from?

Comment: you can use hidden field to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this very specific scenario, you can actually use the Trim function to get rid of those white-spaces (including CR/LF). i.e.,

```
var text = spanspanBoxCode.InnerText.Trim();
```

However, this totally doesn't seem right, since the span's content is not posted to the server on postbacks. So you should not expect to alter the span contents by JavaScript, click some button, and magically retrieve the span's content via the above code.

If this is what you are trying to do, add a "hidden" element to your html, so that you can set its value by JavaScript. Then, on the server side, you can easily retrieve it.

Comment: I found the issue - the span itself included the extra spacing and formatting.